# Something named after a city

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

I'm looking for something that is named after a city. All the information you need is contained in [this map](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QcN8LwCapDTZoxytN2UNDRXiDPbk_8kY&usp=sharing).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

> DARMSTADTIUM
>  Which is an element named after Darmstadt, Germany

This is found from:

> Each place on the map shows an object (river, island, building, etc.) which has the shape of a letter. Combining the letters in order gives the answer.

Images:

> [image: D]
>  [image: A]
>  [image: R]
>  [image: M]
>  [image: S]
>  [image: T]
>  [image: A]
>  [image: D]
>  [image: T]
>  [image: I]
>  [image: U]
>  [image: M]